# Setting up Non-Public Properties using Moq Functional Syntax

Tags: moq

Anyone know if the Moq functional syntax supports setups for Non-Public properties? I noticed that it doesn't work.

NOTE: This is for the functional syntax.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual int FooProperty { get; protected set; }
}
```

This doesn't throw an error, but fails to mock FooProperty

```
Mock.Of<Foo>(x => x.FooProperty == 1);
```

The regular syntax works fine.

```
var mockFoo = new Mock<Foo>(); mockFoo.SetupGet(x=>x.FooProperty)
    .Returns(1)
```

Comment: Please show some sample code you're trying to mock, the moq setup and any errors you're getting.

Comment: To mock an internal member doesn't make any sense to me. Could you please give a sample, so I understand the need for to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth looking at the Pex/Moles tool from Microsoft Research. Moles is used to create accessors for non-public stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It will support mocking of internal properties if you add an assembly attribute to the assembly containing the class under test (add to AssemblyInfo.cs):

```
// This assembly is the default dynamic assembly generated Castle DynamicProxy, 
// used by Moq. Paste in a single line.
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

(You would also have to add an InternalsVisibleTo entry for your test project, of course.)

If you do this, you can mock any internal property in the assembly to which this is added.  If you want to mock private or protected properties, I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that directly.  If they're protected, you could create a Dummy inheritor and give it public methods or properties that access/manipulate its protected members.  For private, there's really nothing you can do, I believe.